# Selecting a subsection from ms access for buffer

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a select statement that is working on SqlClient:

```
     command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 20 ID 
                            FROM Tank 
                            WHERE ID NOT IN 
                                   (SELECT TOP 10 " + "ID 
                                    FROM Tank 
                                    ORDER BY ID) 
                            ORDER BY ID";
```

Trying to use the same command in OLEDBCommand doesnt work and gives a syntax error Close to NOT IN. SO I figured I'd us NOT Exists but that too is not working.. Here is the command:

```
  command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 20 ID 
                         FROM Tank AS Table1 
                         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 10 ID 
                               FROM Tank AS Table2 
                               WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID 
                               ORDER BY ID) 
                         ORDER BY ID";
```

The command executes but it always returns empty. I tried just using exists to see if it works and I do infact return the first 10 rows. I need the last 10 and MS Access doesnt appear to accept NOT IN.

Any Advice?

---

EDIT:

The command  (command) I create is then added to adapter.SelectCommand (adapter.SelectCommand = command)and then I perform a adapter.Fill(Table) where Table is a DataTable. This works when I use the following command (without the NOT):

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 20 ID 
                                FROM Tank 
                                WHERE ID IN 
                                       (SELECT TOP 10 " + "ID 
                                        FROM Tank 
                                        ORDER BY ID) 
                                ORDER BY ID";
```

However, when I add the NOT the Adapter.Fill(Table) just stalls and gets stuck. It never leaves. This is the command:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 20 ID 
                                FROM Tank 
                                WHERE ID IN 
                                       (SELECT TOP 10 " + "ID 
                                        FROM Tank 
                                        ORDER BY ID) 
                                ORDER BY ID";
```

But when I add the NOT

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between `table` and `1`.  Presumably you mean:

```
SELECT TOP 20 ID
FROM Tank AS Table1
------------------^
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 10 ID FROM Tank AS Table2 WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID ORDER BY ID)
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The old NULL in sub-select problem?

If the sub-select returns one (or more) NULL's, the "NOT IN (sub-select" will return an empty result set.

NOT IN is a bit dangerous. Either re-write as NOT EXISTS, or make sure the sub-select never returns any NULL's. (For example by adding IS NOT NULL to the sub-select.)